# 301 www redirect only redirects home page. How to redirect every inner page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This redirect is only applying to the homepage, it is not site wide.

ex: `e-airllc.com` will re-direct to `www.e-airllc.com`
but `e-airllc.com/about` won't re-direct to `www.e-airllc.com/about`

Should I be concerned about having this SEO issue?

Comment: Can you show your existing rule?

Comment: That is funny. I asked you to show your existing rules and you're asking us for the idea.